# can we get electrical energy from gravitational energy?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Now I'm trying to give an answer of the question. Satellite rotates about earth by the gravitational force of earth. Now if we place the satellite in such an orbit so that it rotate in opposite to earth rotation and having a greater angular rotational speed.

Now there is an existence of earth magnetic field. Though it is very poor but strength of magnetic field is not the major factor of energy conversion. So as in electrical machine rotor rotates and stator gives magnetic field and electricity generates is it not possible to extract gravitational energy by using satellite as rotor and geomagnetic field as stator? how much it is effective?

Edited: OK eventually this question becomes duplicate. Now I am asking how can we store this energy. Can we store this energy? or not.

Comment: You would pull satellites out of orbit doing that. But as for using gravity to get electricity, think water wheel

Comment: NASA has even run a test flight on powering satellites from the motional EMF of their orbit through the Earth magnetic field. You have to run out a couple of long antennas, and as @Jim says it will eventually deorbit the bird, but it works.

Comment: Note that a retrograde orbit does not have any higher orbital speed than a standard orbit.  It will have a higher speed relative to the surface or the ambient magnetic field, but not a whole lot for a low orbit satellite.  It is probably not worth the extra work of getting to a retrograde orbit.

Comment: But if I rotate the satellite along the orbit passing through North pole and south pole then we can utilise the whole orbital velocity.